Prove $f$ is continuous at $x = 0$ in the topological way
I want to prove that $f: [0, +\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)= \sqrt{x}$ is continuous at $x = 0$ in the topological way, that is (from Wikipedia): $F: X \to Y$ is continuous at $x = x_0 \in X$ if for every neighbourhood $V$ of $F(x)$ in $Y$, there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ in $X$ such that $F(U) \subseteq V$.
Attempts
So $x = 0 \in X$. I chose a neighbourhood of $0$ in $X$, like $U = [0, 1/2)$. Then $f(U) = [0, \sqrt{1/2})$.
Does it suffice then to say I can choose, for every $\delta > 0$, $V$ such that $V = [0, \sqrt{1/2} + \delta)$?
In this way I have $f(U) \subseteq V$.
I don't know, I think it's not correct and not that simple...

Your $V$ is not a neighborhood of 0, for a start. But even if it were, you were asked to show that some property holds for all neighborhoods of $0 \in \mathbb{R}$, so I don't think there's really even a question of whether this can be correct at all, no?

@BenSteffan I cannot have a proper neighbourhood of $0$, since $0 - \delta$ doesn't belong to $X$. And for the "all" part, well this is something I cannot understand how to do. How to prove this for them all?

The codomain does have “proper neighborhoods of $0$”. And yeah, have you ever proved a statement of the form $\forall x \exists y P(x,y)$? It’s not so hard in this circumstance.

@Heidegger We're talking about the codomain. $0 - \delta$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}$ just fine.

You must not choose V. V must be abitrary. Let be $V$ an open neighbourhood of $f(0) = 0$. You can choose a tiny open ball $B:=B_{\delta}(0) \subset V$. Now is $f^{-1}(B) = [0, \delta^2)$. Choose $U := [0,\frac{\delta^2}{2})$. $U$ is open in $[0,\infty)$ and $0 \in U$. Furthermore $f(U) \subset B \subset V$.

Simply take $U = [0,\delta^2)$.
